# can't add foreign key constraint in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table buys (    
user_id INT(11) not null,    
software_id INT(11) not null,    
associated_id INT(11) not null,    
primary key (associated_id),    
foreign key (software_id) references software,    
foreign key (user_id) references users,    
foreign key (associated_id) references associated);
```

I have a ternary relationship associated table having total participation and a key constraint but cannot add foreign key constraints

Comment: what is your error ?

Comment: And those tables have the specified columns as primary keys?

Comment: Your foreign keys only mention the referenced table, not the attribute. It should be something like `foreign key (software_id) references software (id)`

Comment: yes they have those columns as keys

Comment: Your primary key is also a foreign key, are you sure your primary key is not something like `primary key (user_id, software_id, associated_id)` ?

Comment: ı want to create a table for a ternary relationship with a key+participation constraint on associated table. so shoul its primary key be only associated_id or three of them?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE products(
   prd_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
   cat_id int not null,
   FOREIGN KEY fk_cat(cat_id)
   REFERENCES categories(cat_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

In your case:

```
foreign key (software_id) references software -> here column name is missing in software table
```